# File transfer error in tftp

Tags: tftp

I tried to transfer files using tftp but I am getting file transfer error.Upon investigation I found out that the file in.tftpd is missing in sbin.How to solve this issue?? Should I reinstall tftp in my machine

Comment: You've not provided any OS/product & release details, so looking at the *amd64* and *kinetic* release I don't see what you expect to see anyway - https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/amd64/tftp/filelist

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: I downloaded some libraries ..now it's working..thanks